# Partitioning of Ubuntu 10.04 server on KVM?

Tags: server, partitioning, zimbra

I am installing Ubuntu 10.04 server on a KVM virtual machine. The server will be used to install Zimbra mail server, which installs under /opt/zimbra. As Zimbra is being used, it needs more storage. I decided to put /opt on a separate partition, so that I can resize that partition later on if needed.

I first did a test install with guided partition and ended up with a 254.8 MB for /boot and 1.5 GB for swap. So I think those are good numbers to use in my manual partition and I ended up with the following partition:

```
SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 34.4 GB ATA QEMU HARDDISK
    #1   primary   254.8 MB   f   ext2   /boot
    #5   logical   1.5 GB     f   swap   swap
    #6   logical   8.0 GB     f   ext4   /
    #7   logical   24.6 GB    f   ext3   /opt
```

/opt is set to ext3, because Zimbra installation requires a ext3 file system. My question is if this partition works well with a mail server. If not, any suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

Some remarks...

- The 8.0 Gb root is more than we use on our servers.
- Zimbra uses MySQL. MySQL by default stores it databases in `/etc/` so that might be a caveat. From the specifications I assume they store it in `/opt/zimbra` so that might be taken care of by them.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning MySQL. I checked my.cnf, MySQL is totally installed under /opt/zimbra.

Comment: Then you should be good to go! :D